# Is it possible to derive the sum of the tangent or cotangent from this?

Tags: summation, intuition

So we can suppose that we can find the *finite* sum

$$\sum_{x=a}^b{ \tan{(x)} + \cot{(x)} } \tag{1}$$

for essentially all integer values of $x$.

I'm wondering, can we derive either:

$$\sum_{x=a}^b{ \tan{(x)} } \qquad\text{ or }\qquad \sum_{x=a}^b{ \cot{(x)} } \tag{2}$$

from this sum?

It may be possible to use substitution for $x$ in (1), but there is no guarantee that we can find the sums for non-integer values of $x$ in (1).

*I know that it is possible to find the sums in (2).  However, I'm primarily interested in if we can derive either sum in (2) from (1).*

Comment: I suspect that $f(a,b)=\sum_{n=a}^b (\tan(n)+\cot(n))$ is $1-1$ on $\{(a,b)\in\mathbb N^2\mid 0<a\leq b\}$, so technically possible, but would there be a continuous function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that would take $f(a,b)$ to $\sum_{n=a}^b \tan n$?

Comment: $\tan n+\cot n=2/\sin(2n)$?

Comment: When you say "essentially integers $x$," that is confusing. Do you mean pairs $a,b$? Note that $\cot x$ is not defined for $x=0$, so you have to have $ab>0$ - that is, $a,b$ the same sign, neither zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  Sorry - I mean any pairs of $a$ and $b$ that exclude $\cot{(0)}$.

Comment: @mike:  I've been looking up the summation of $2/ \sin{(2n)}$, but there's not a great deal of information out there on it.  Is there any chance of a fairly simple formula/equation for this sum?

Comment: @MattGroff. I am not aware such thing either.